# VueJS - nesting v-on:click and v-if makes components disappear

Tags: vuejs2

Whenever I nest a v-on:click inside a v-if, the whole div disappears. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div v-if="!signInIsHidden1" >
  <div v-on:click="!signInIsHidden = signInIsHidden" style="text-align:center"><br>Register</div></div>
```

Comment: This: `!signInIsHidden = signInIsHidden` isn't valid JavaScript syntax. I think you meant `signInIsHidden = !signInIsHidden`. Better yet, move that assignment to a VueJS method.

Comment: May you please give an example how to put it in a method?

Comment: I have shown an example in an answer.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the invalid syntax you mentioned. 

What if I really meant the initial state of everything inside signInIsHidden1 to be invisible (hence !signInIsHidden1) . I placed that inner v-on:click there to make it invisible again when clicked (after it is triggered visible by a separate button not in this div)

Comment: The syntax `!a = a` will result in a "Invalid left-hand side in assignment". It looks like you're trying to toggle the state of the boolean, but that would require you to do `a = !a` (note the location of the `!`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VueJS expressions must be valid JavaScript.

This:

```
!signInIsHidden = signInIsHidden
```

is a little backwards. I think you meant:

```
signInIsHidden = !signInIsHidden
```

Better yet, move that assignment to a VueJS method:

```
...
methods: {
    toggleSignIn: function() {
        this.signInIsHidden = !this.signInIsHidden;
    }
}
...

<div :click="toggleSignIn"></div>
```

Also, you have `signInIsHidden1` in the outer div, but without the `1` in the click event.